# Software center gets stuck

Tags: software-installation

Currently, whenever I try to install a new app or click on os updates from software center, the installation always gets stuck in the middle. I think the problem may have to do with the fact that many websites and servers are blocked in my current country of residence (china). I have configured my network to use the proxy across the system but it does not help.

Comment: Have you tried changing your settings so that you're pulling from repos in China?

Comment: @b_laoshi how can I do that?

Comment: [This how-to](http://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-update-ubuntu-12-04.html) is for an older version, but it should still work just fine. Avoid `mirror.neu.edu.cn`. It's missing all kinds of packages. Don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update` after changing mirrors.

Comment: @b_laoshi Hi, the how-to instruction does not help because there is no "edit" tab(there is not a single tab in fact) for software center on my ubuntu.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, you can find the program by searching the applications for *software*. See [this image](https://postimg.org/image/4hflz6f17/).